# How to set permissions for apache2 to let user create or edit files in /var/www/

Tags: apache, ubuntu, permissions

I'm using Ubuntu 14 server from DO, with LAMP stack installed, i followed the instruction here to install flask on ubuntu because my main purpose was to use Flask on my website.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

During the test, when user connects to "http:/myvpsip/createfile/" which creates a new file on the current folder /var/www/, I got error from Apache saying that the file cannot be created, "permission denied".

I tried again using PHP script that create a new file on the same directory /var/www/ but got the same problem. Both of the trials were done using root account. I tried to chmod the www folder to 755 or 777 and they are not working.

My question is, how do I set permission for apache2 that when users browse the website they will be able to create/edit file on the current directory?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because when you installed your application, you did so as the root user. All your application  files and directories are owned by root.

If you ls -l on /var/www and look inside the FlaskApp folder structure, you will likely see permissions set like this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root
```

When Apache runs, it runs on behalf of a main process owned by the user root and several child processes  owned by the user www-data. So essentially, Apache is running as if logged in as user www-data.

When your application needs to do a file or folder operation (its running on behalf of Apache www-data user), the public/world permission bits are used since Apache child processes are not running as root user and not as root group.

Looking above, we see that only the read bit is set for the public/world permissions - no write. And that is where the problem lies.

One way to solve this is to make everything under /var/www/mywebsite owned by the user root and the group www-data. This sets things up so that only the root user can have full permissions and www-data (everyone else) can only read and execute (no write).

When you setup your website, you should set it up to be under its own separate folder. This way you can have multiple virtual domains (i.e. more websites) added later on. Assuming 'mywebsite' is where your domain is and you have already installed your application software (Flask) within it:

```
cd /var/www/mywebsite
chown -R root:www-data /var/www
```

You then as the system administrator, need to understand the application and go through the folders and files setting permissions. Apply permissions generally, then on a case by case basis.

For most directories (750)

```
- Only root can rwx directory
- www-data can only read and execute directory
- no public/world bits set as it makes no sense (*)
```

For directories that can be changed by web application (770)

```
- Root can rwx directory
- www-data can rwx directory
- no public/world bits set as it makes no sense (*)
- for uploading files, creating images, documents, etc by the users of the site
```

For most files (640)

```
- Never set the execute bit to avoid execution of misplaced shell or executable files
- PHP, Perl, etc. are just text files. They have nothing to do with exec permission
- No group write bit set
- Read must be set for owner and group else they cant see the web document
```

For special case where files need to be changed (660)

```
- Set group write bit if you want www-data users to create things
```

(*) Because all users who visit Apache are running on behalf of www-data

Comment: very insightful reply, that helps me a lot, since im more like a dev than an administrator so there are a lot of thing that I need to learn. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry to dig it up, I followed your instruction, i have my flaskapp already up and running at var/www/flaskapp. I then logged in as root and did "chown -R root:www-data /var/www". I still cannot be able to edit or write a file a user, meant that I wanted to edit test.txt residing in var/www/flaskapp/test.txt, i still got "Permission Denied"

Comment: You need to change the permission settings for the directories and files for /var/www/flaskapp so that they are writeable. Try chmod -R 777 /var/www/flaskapp. After you get that to work, then go to each directory and consider files and apply chmod based on what I wrote above (i.e. 750, 640)